# mmc snap-ins extension

Tags: c#, .net, mmc, snap-in

Looking for how to create a snap-in extension.

I know how to create STANDALONE snap-ins but, also need to look into the snap-in extensions.

I'd like to create them in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find answer in the Microsoft Windows SDKs Samples. For those interested: 
Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.1\Samples\SysMgmt\MMC3.0