# First step to create a C# MMC Snap-In in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, sdk, visual-studio-2019, mmc3

I was trying what was on this page, even though it says that the content is not updated regularly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms692759(v=vs.85)

I created a C# class library, and pasted in the code at the bottom.

I think this first issue is this:

```
using Microsoft.ManagementConsole;
```

is not finding anything.  And because of that, the classes that it is supposed to inherit from (SnapInInstaller and SnapIn) are not found.

[image]

When I try to find an assembly to reference, nothing is found.

[image]

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 because that's what works with Microsoft BizTalk Server 2020.

I also tried a really old sample from CodeProject, but it has C++ code in it, and my understanding is that now we should be able to create it all in C#.  Any reference or link to any good documentation or example would greatly be appreciated.

I tried the Windows SDK based on this StackOverflow: [mmc snap-ins extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930369/mmc-snap-ins-extension)
I downloaded and installed: 22621.1778.230511-2102.ni_release_svc_prod3_WindowsSDK.iso

It installed the following selections to "D:\Windows Kit".  It didn't put anything in Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.1\Samples\SysMgmt\MMC3.0 as mentioned on the above link.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@NealWalters, based on my test, I also reproduced your problem that I could not find the MCC3 class library. I find that we need to download the sdk from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/mmc/mmc-3.0/ms692740(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#where-applicable). However, I find the download link is useless. I recommend that you could submit the issue to recommend that Microsoft to fix the download link in their [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/issues).

Thanks for your understanding and support.

Best Regards,

Jack